# use service invoke function in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Is possible to call invoke function from a service in symfony?

this is the controller

```
class FooController extends AbstractController
{
    private $fooService;

    public function __construct(FooService $fooService)
    {
        $this->fooService = $fooService;
    }

    #[Route('/foo', name: 'app_foo')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
       
        return new Response($this->fooService->__invoke());
        //is not possible to do 
        //return new Response($this->fooService());
    }
}
```

and the service

```
namespace App\Service;

class FooService
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

I have to call `__invoke` function explicitly instead to make $`this->fooService()` is not possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP the method call has higher priority than property access so you need to use parentheses.

($this->fooService)()

To access the property and call it.

Comment: Just take a look at [What is voting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)